# Looking for a simple way to time the execution of readProcess (without criterion)

Tags: haskell

I'm executing ssh commands with `readProcess` (from the `System.Process` package), and I'd like to time how long the execution takes and print that along with the command output.

I know it's possible to time this accurately with criterion, but criterion seems to spend time doing a lot of setup and teardown as well as printing extra output. I'm not looking to run a full benchmark, just display how long the ssh command took to run.

So far I've tried the `System.TimeIt` package, but the results are incorrect. For example, this should report at least 5 seconds (just running `sleep 5`):

```
>>> timeIt $ readProcess "sleep" ["5"] []
CPU time:   0.04s
```

Here's what `System.TimeIt` is doing under the hood:

```
-- |Wrap an 'IO' computation so that it prints out the execution time.
timeIt :: IO a -> IO a
timeIt ioa = do
    (t, a) <- timeItT ioa
    printf "CPU time: %6.2fs\n" t
    return a

-- |Wrap an 'IO' computation so that it returns execution time is seconds as well as the     real value.
timeItT :: IO a -> IO (Double, a)
timeItT ioa = do
    t1 <- getCPUTime
    a <- ioa
    t2 <- getCPUTime
    let t :: Double
    t = fromIntegral (t2-t1) * 1e-12
    return (t, a)
```

It seems straightforward enough, but I can't figure out a way to force the execution of `a <- ioa`. Annotating with `!` seems to make no difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here isn't lazy evaluation--it's that `sleep` doesn't waste any CPU time on computing things, it just makes the program pause its execution during the given delay. So `TimeIt` is correctly reporting the amount of time your IO action spent on computation.

Instead of `getCPUTime`, you want to get wall clock time before and after the action that you want to time. Try `getCurrentTime` in `Data.Time.Clock`.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. ```getCurrentTime``` gives the desired result.